# JavaScript inheritance JQuery vs Prototype DOM Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, prototypejs

I am not trying to ask another JQuery vs. Prototype vs... topic as I have already read 5+ of those on these forums and have been able to gain a lot of knowledge from them. My question is more directly related to wanting the ability to use inheritance for basic classes and not actually sure what would be a good choice.

To be brief, I have the requirement to be able to control theoretical objects in javascript and manipulate them based on user input then display them.

I have used JQuery and enjoy how easy it is to modify the DOM (which appears to be it's main goal). However from all the readings I have done, it seems that JQuery has no intention of assisting you in dealing with classes, inheritance etc. If I have already chosen JQuery to display and manipulate the data what would be a good choice to assist me with the inheritance issue.

My first thought was Mootools or Prototype, however prototype DOM Extension seems to be a very bad approach and would rather wait for Prototype 2.0 unless this isn't an issue on commonly supported browsers now.

I had also read about Base2, Joose, and JS.Class, but don't know if they will do what I am hoping for either. 
Any suggestions based on the above information would be great, again, I am not trying to figure out the pro's and con's of the commonly used JS frameworks.

Comment: You're right about jQuery - the primary use is DOM manipulation. What's your actual question? Are you looking for a library to help you simulate class-based inheritance in JavaScript?

Comment: @MattBall Java has this little known `class` keyword. It's quite useful.

Comment: Whoops, typo... is that all you were pointing out?

Comment: @MattBall yes, it was one of those not actually funny jokes.

Comment: I am looking for both clean OO (if that makes any sense) and in a way what Raynos said, something that resembles OOP like Java or C or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why emulate classical inheritance?

What's wrong with functions and `.prototype`?

```
var SomeObject = function(data) {
    this.data = data;
}

SomeObject.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    return this.data;
}
```

Do it the old fashioned way.

If you want to use anything besides jQuery I would recommend [`underscore`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) for it's syntactic sugar.

If you must emulate classical OO, I would recommend [`oorja`](http://maxpert.github.com/oorja/) as it's the lesser of evils.

Comment: Agreed, trying to overlay classical inheritance in JS is just not the right way to do it.

Comment: Why use Mootools or Prototype.js at all if we can already do OO and inheritance so easily in JS? 
underscore and oorja both look like they would assist in what I was looking for.

Comment: @Craig because Mootools and Prototype aren't "inheritance" libraries. They're analogous to jQuery - libraries that provide a consistent API across browers, in addition to providing UI widgets, effects, etc.

Comment: I will admit my OP was a bit misleading (probably a lot), I had stated inheritance as that is what I had been looking at comparably right before asking the question. I am looking for a OO JavaScript framework that would be able to work with the jQuery libraries and still be small when both are loaded. JQuery seems to use OO JavaScript, but doesn't enhance it in any way (perhaps there is no need and I guess that is an answer that would work for me as well).

Comment: To be more specific, I was looking for something like this [link](http://ryanflorence.com/object-oriented-jquery-with-mootools-pigs-take-flight/)